# Why can't a Gremlin GraphTraversal be captured as a Groovy variable?

Tags: groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am experimenting with the [traversal examples](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M5/#_the_graph_process) from the TinkerPop3 documentation. Having loaded up the [classic graph](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M5/#intro) with `g = TinkerFactory.createClassic()`, at the Gremlin shell:

```
gremlin> marko = g.v(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko
==>v[1]
```

However:

```
gremlin> marko = g.V().has('name', 'marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko
gremlin>
```

Why does the second form not capture `v[1]`?

---

Given the second form, attemping to use the variable results in an error:

```
gremlin> marko.out('knows')
The traversal strategies are complete and the traversal can no longer have steps added to it
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

Comment: Check the type; `v` always returns a `Vertext` while `has` is generic.

Comment: @DaveNewton, and the generic is not captured in the variable?

Comment: Try to actually *do* something with it instead of relying on the shell's default display.

Comment: @DaveNewton updated beneath horizontal rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dealing with different class types from each of those results.  Consider my console session below:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createClassic()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> marko = g.v(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko.class
==>class com.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex
```

The above yields a `Vertex` but as you can see below:

```
gremlin> marko = g.V().has('name','marko')
==>v[1]
gremlin> marko.class
==>class com.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.process.graph.TinkerGraphTraversal
```

you get a `Traversal` instance.  You see output to the console of `v[1]` because the console has automatically iterated the result for you.  Since you have iterated it, `marko` becomes empty:

```
gremlin> marko.hasNext()
==>false
```

If you want to manually iterate then do this:

```
gremlin> marko = g.V().has('name','marko');null
==>null
gremlin> marko.hasNext()
==>true
gremlin> marko
==>v[1]
```